# How to set checkpoint in dynamodb streams KCL adapter for lambda that triggers every N minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams, amazon-kcl

I wanted to access DynamoDB Streams for the last N minutes using DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter by triggering lambda every N minutes by scheduling CloudWatch Events. How can I keep track of last processed record when lambda is triggered next time so that I can continue from last processed record.

I saw from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.Walkthrough.CompleteProgram.html
that I can use checkpoint to keep track of last processed record, but my doubt is where is this stored? How can I use this checkpoint for my next lambda trigger after N minutes?